# Why compiler does not see method of base class when using CRTP

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

I have the following piece of code:

```
struct Iface
{
    virtual int Read() = 0;

    int Read(int x) {
        return Read() + x;
    }
};

template <typename Impl>
struct Crtp : public Iface
{
    virtual int Read() {
        return static_cast<Impl&>(*this).ReadImpl();
    }
    //using Iface::Read;
};

struct IfaceImpl : public Crtp<IfaceImpl>
{
    int ReadImpl() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    IfaceImpl impl;
    impl.Read(24); // compilation error

    Iface& iface = impl;
    iface.Read(24); // always compiles successfully
}
```

Both msvc, gcc and clang reject this code, they cannot find method `Read(int x)`

However if I uncomment `using Iface::Read` in `Crtp` my code compiles successfully.

Note that if I take a reference to Iface I can call `Read(int x)`

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Your problem has nothing to do with CRTP. It's a name hiding issue that may happen in a normal inheritance scenario.

When you call `impl.Read(24);`, the member function name `Read` can't be found at the class scope of `IfaceImpl`. Then the scope of base class `Crtp` will be examined, and the name `Read` found there. Then name lookup stops, so `int Read(int x)` in the further base class `Iface` won't be considered for overload resolution, even though it is more appropriate here.

By `using Iface::Read;` you're introducing the name `Read` into the class scope of `Crtp`. Then it could be found and selected by overload resolution correctly.

And if you call it via `Iface` reference, the name lookup will work well.

Or you can call it explicitly (and ugly) by `impl.Iface::Read(24);`.

See [Unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> ... name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.